# How to print corresponding weights of features in scikit SVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

As in SVM there corresponds to every feature f[i], a weight w[i] as coefficient. When all features are scaled, w[i] must represent importance of feature f[i] so I am looking to print this order of importance. So I wrote a quick code, and used clf.coef_ to obtain all w[i]. But result is bit wierd, for n_features=2, clf.coef_ outputs 10x2 matrix!

```py
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from pandas import DataFrame
X,Y=make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=5, n_features=2)

clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True)
clf.fit(X,Y)

print(clf.coef_)
```

Output of this code is :-

```
[[-0.14808725 -0.30415025]
 [ 0.01612808  0.43529163]
 [-1.06694209 -0.27738544]
 [-0.13195668 -0.27799574]
 [ 0.03588147  0.13657989]
 [ 0.04273599  0.65849432]
 [ 0.68017938 -0.64049715]
 [-0.09071154 -0.22828399]
 [-0.01494555 -0.1300181 ]
 [ 0.10260101 -0.36918253]]
```

So what does this 10x2 matrix represent and more importantly how can I obtain all w[i] values which corresponds to each feature weight.

Comment: Please help to upvote if you find the answer useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linear SVM, note that the result is a hyperplane that separates the classes as best as possible. The weights represent this hyperplane, by giving you the coordinates of a vector which is orthogonal to the hyperplane - these are the coefficients given by svm.coef_

**Reason for 10*2 matrix**: (your numbers of classes is 5 and number of features is 2)
(and the documentation of sklearn is clear and helpful)

SVC implements the “one-against-one” for multi- class classification. If n_class is the number of classes, then n_class * (n_class - 1) / 2 classifiers are constructed and each one trains data from two classes.

SVM's coef_ attribute outputs the same and the array is : [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]

If you want to have just 5 classifiers instead of 10, you can either:

1. Use decision_function_shape = "ovr" while you define/fit your clf.
2. Or you can use Linear SVC (lin_clf = svm.LinearSVC()) (This will use ovr by default)